# Why is ogr2ogr trying to open the app it's being run from?

Tags: python, geojson, gdal, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to write some script using the `ogr2ogr` function in python:

```py
convertstring = 'ogr2ogr -f r"GeoJSON" r"Output.GeoJson" -select * -where "layer = building" r"' + filepath+'"'
os.system(convertstring)
```

but I keep getting this error:

> **FAILURE:  Unable to open datasource `myApp.py' with the following drivers.**

This is a little odd - myApp.py is the app that I'm running so there is no need to open it, and I'm not asking it to open it.  Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`os.system()` uses a shell to execute the command, so that asterisk gets expanded to all the filenames in the current working directory.

Unrelated to that, I strongly doubt that all those `r"` thingies do what you want them to do (whatever that is!).

You might be better off using `subprocess.run()`.